# Feign client cannot find application with @ sign in name

Tags: spring-cloud-feign

I successfully registered my application with name `my-service@zone1.com` but when I'm trying to find it using `DynamicFeignClient` it is failing.

```java
        GreetingClient greetingClient = dynamicFeignClient.getFeignClientBuilder().forType(GreetingClient.class, "my-service@zone1.com").build();
        return greetingClient.greeting();
```

I get an error

```
Load balancer does not contain an instance for the service zone1.com

feign.FeignException$ServiceUnavailable: [503] during [GET] to [http://my-service@zone1.com/get-greeting]
```

When I encode the url I get `Service id not legal hostname (my-service%40zone1.com)`

Is it possible to make it work with Feign client or the only option is to register service without special characters in its name?